# JQuery (3.3.1) checkbox combination fails to return expected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox

Having a little trouble with JQuery (version 3.3.1) checkbox implementation. See code sample below.

**The problem**

Selecting every combination works flawlessly except one, and I can't seem to pinpoint flaws in the code. The console doesn't complain when selecting the nonworking combination either. Nonworking combination:

[✓] Check Box 1
 
 [   ] Check Box 2
 
 [✓] Check Box 3
 
 [✓] Check Box 4

Things to keep in mind:

- Same checkbox combo fails there.
- Every other combo works perfectly and returns expected results
- I'm working locally with the downloaded, uncompressed **`jquery-3.3.1.js`**. Because the source refers to JQuery 2.1.3, I also downloaded the uncompressed **`jquery-2.1.3.js`** file. Same checkbox combo fails when referring to either JQuery version.
- Code from source was not changed at all on my local machine.

Seems there's some flaw in the actual source code but can't seem to pinpoint any syntax errors or anything esle missing.

```js
 $("#doIt").on("click", function () {
     var check = $('input:checked:checkbox[name=cc]');
     var id = '';
     $.each($(check), function (index) {
         id += $(this).attr('id');
     });
     if ($(check).is(':checked')) {
         switch (id) {
             case 'c1':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c2':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c3c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c2c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c2c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2c3c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c2c3c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
         }
     } else {
         alert('Un Checked');
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cc" />
<label for="c3"><span></span>Check Box 3</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="cc" />
<label for="c4"><span></span>Check Box 4</label>
<br />
<button id="doIt" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Not sure what you try to do here, though the `case 'c1c3c4'` was missing in your test list. Here is an updated, working version: https://jsfiddle.net/xmcv5x7h/15/

Comment: I voted to close this as a simple typo. It also has no value for other users either, not being a real code issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JQuery. You were simply missing a `case` branch that matches that combination.

You need to add: `case c1c3c4:`.

```js
$("#doIt").on("click", function () {
     var check = $("input[name='cc']:checked");
     var id = '';
     $.each($(check), function (index) {
         id += $(this).attr('id');
     });
     if ($(check).is(':checked')) {
         switch (id) {
             case 'c1':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c2':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c3c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c2c3':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             // You were missing this    
             case 'c1c3c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;                 
             case 'c1c2c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c2c3c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
             case 'c1c2c3c4':
                 console.log(id);
                 break;
         }
     } else {
         alert('Un Checked');
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cc" />
<label for="c3"><span></span>Check Box 3</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="cc" />
<label for="c4"><span></span>Check Box 4</label>
<br />
<button id="doIt" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: If that isn't a typo, then what is? ... and has no value to anybody else than the OP